# Reactive filtering and adding in shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shiny-reactivity, shinyapps

I'm trying to create a reactive count based off distinctive values.

So let's say you adjust the age slide to `Age >= 50` and a `Current Score >= 10` it returns a count of 1571 unique customer IDs, which are then showed in the table. Then you click the `Add to List` button and those 1571 are added. But at the same time, those 1571 are also removed from the filtered dataset you're working with. Now all of the inputs reset themselves after you make that add. Then let's say you want to add all hispanic people with a `Current Score >= 20`, so you move  The way I have it setup, it would return a value of 310, but with the filtering setup to what I'm trying to achieve, it would be returning only the unique Customer IDs that haven't been filtered out yet, and those would be added to the total count/table.

Does this make sense?

```
df <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gooponyagrinch/sample_data/master/datasheet.csv')

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column("",
           width = 10, offset = 1,
           tags$h3("Select Area"),
           panel(
             sliderInput("current", "Current Score", min = 0, max = 100, value = 20),
             sliderInput("projected", "Projected Score", min = 0, max = 100, value = 20),
             sliderInput("age", "Age", min = 18, max = max(df$age), value = c(18,24)),
             checkboxGroupInput("ethnicity", label = "Ethnicity", 
                                choices = list("Caucasian" = "Caucasian",
                                               "African-American" = "African-American",
                                               "Hispanic" = "Hispanic",
                                               "Other" = "Other")),
             checkboxInput('previous', label = "Previous Sale"),
             checkboxInput('warm', label = "Warm Lead"),
             actionButton("button", "Add to List")), 
           textOutput("counter"),
           DT::dataTableOutput("table")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  filtered_df <- reactive({

    res <- df %>% filter(current_grade >= input$current)
    res <- res %>% filter(projected_grade >= input$projected)
    res <- res %>% filter(age >= input$age[1] & age <= input$age[2])
    res <- res %>% filter(ethnicity %in% input$ethnicity | is.null(input$ethnicity))

    if(input$previous == TRUE)
      res <- res %>% filter(previous_sale == 1)

    if(input$warm == TRUE)
      res <- res %>% filter(warm_lead == 1)

    res
  })

  output$counter <- renderText({
    res <- filtered_df() %>% select(customer_id) %>% n_distinct()
    res
  })

  output$table <- renderDataTable({
    res <- filtered_df() %>% distinct(customer_id)
    res
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Any way you could share the data or make your code work with example data. Would be much easier to understand what you are after.

Comment: @teofil Ah I thought I made that edit earlier. Sorry, it's in the new script now. Also:

`df <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gooponyagrinch/sample_data/master/datasheet.csv')`

Comment: @gooponyagrinch Your question is very unclear. Maybe post screenshot of R shiny app of each step you want to achieve

Answer (score 2):

This should do it

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)
df <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gooponyagrinch/sample_data/master/datasheet.csv")

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column("",
      width = 10, offset = 1,
      tags$h3("Select Area"),
      div(
        sliderInput("current", "Current Score",
          min = 0, max = 100, value = 20
        ),
        sliderInput("projected", "Projected Score",
          min = 0, max = 100, value = 20
        ),
        sliderInput("age", "Age",
          min = 18, max = max(df$age), value = c(18, 24)
        ),
        checkboxGroupInput("ethnicity",
          label = "Ethnicity",
          choices = list(
            "Caucasian" = "Caucasian",
            "African-American" = "African-American",
            "Hispanic" = "Hispanic",
            "Other" = "Other"
          )
        ),
        checkboxInput("previous", label = "Previous Sale"),
        checkboxInput("warm", label = "Warm Lead"),
        actionButton("button", "Add to List")
      ),
      textOutput("counter"),
      p("Remaining Input Table"),
      DT::dataTableOutput("input_table"),
      p("Filtered Table"),
      DT::dataTableOutput("filtered_table"),
      p("Accumulated Table"),
      DT::dataTableOutput("accumulated_table")
    )
  )
)

accumulated_df <- reactiveVal(NULL)
df <- reactiveVal(df)

server <- function(input, output, session) {



  filtered_df <- reactive({
    res <- df() %>% filter(current_grade >= input$current)
    res <- res %>% filter(projected_grade >= input$projected)
    res <- res %>% filter(age >= input$age[1] & age <= input$age[2])
    res <- res %>% filter(ethnicity %in% input$ethnicity | is.null(input$ethnicity))

    if (input$previous == TRUE) {
      res <- res %>% filter(previous_sale == 1)
    }

    if (input$warm == TRUE) {
      res <- res %>% filter(warm_lead == 1)
    }

    res
  })

  output$counter <- renderText({
    res <- filtered_df() %>%
      select(customer_id) %>%
      n_distinct()

    res
  })

  observeEvent(input$button, {

    if(! is.null(accumulated_df()))
    accumulated_df(
      union(
        accumulated_df(),
        filtered_df()
      )
    ) else 
      accumulated_df( filtered_df())



    df(setdiff(df(),
               filtered_df())

    )

  })

  output$input_table <- renderDataTable({
    df()
  })
  output$filtered_table <- renderDataTable({
    filtered_df()
  })
  output$accumulated_table <- renderDataTable({
    accumulated_df()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Might I ask what this part does and why it's not on the `server` side:

`accumulated_df2 <- reactiveVal(NULL)
df2 <- reactiveVal(df2)`

Comment: i didnt write any 'df2'  ?

Comment: but in general reactiveVal instantiates a reactive variable that you can reference on the server side. I dont think it needs to be in the serverside to start, but if it does , or you prefer it to be , move it in there.

Comment: https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.3.0/reactiveVal.html

Comment: The `accumulated_df()` reactiveVal is being initialized as a global variable, not a UI one if that’s where the confusion is coming from. 

I would recommend that you initialize it in the server function for the simple reason that storing a reactive in global means that reactive is shared by all sessions of the app. I think the demo solution avoids any consequences from this, but you should make a habit to only use reactives inside server functions